# How do I alter the page title h1 tag from a module?

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

I miss [hook_page_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7)!

I want to create a module that adds some configurable markup to page titles (the H1 tag on the HTML document) for full node pageviews of certain, configurable content types. But according to this [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357755):

> You no longer can change $page['content'] (or, generally speaking, $page[$region_name]) into something completely different.

I know I can override twig templates to achieve this, but can I do that without creating a theme? I'd like this to be a reusable module.

Answer (score 3):

The page title is now a block, so you can [override its template file](https://www.drupal.org/node/2568563).

Answer (score 0):

drupal 8 page title is block so you can use hook

```
function hook_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

     $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
   $variables['title'] = "your custom text here ".$node->getTitle(); 
}
```